# Integral of Form $(a^2 - x^2)^{1/2}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Solve $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{x^2(9-x^2)^{1/2}}\ \mathrm{d}x$

So far, I have used trigonometric substitution, so that
$x = 3\sin y$, $x^2 = 9\sin^2 y$, and $\mathrm{d}x = 3\cos y\ \mathrm{d}y$.

I have worked this out and repeatedly gotten the answer $\dfrac{-1}{y}$, however, this is not the correct answer. Is the method wrong, or am I just making a mistake somewhere in my calculations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's follow your suggestion (and when substituting do **not** use the same variable!) :

$$x=3\sin t\;,\;\;dx=3\cos tdt\implies x^2\sqrt{9-x^2}=9\sin^2t\cdot3\cos t\implies$$

$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{9-x^2}}=3\int\frac{\cos tdt}{27\sin^2t\cos t}=\frac19\int\frac{dt}{\sin^2t}=-\frac19\cot t+C\;\ldots$$

Comment: So when you have 1/(9sin^2t) why is it that you can't simply rewrite that as the original substitution of x^2 ?

Comment: I honestly don't understand your question, @user130996: if we change variables is to use them, don't we?

Comment: Because if we substitute back in, we would get $\displaystyle \frac{1}{9} \int \frac{dt}{\sin^2 t} = \int \frac{dt}{x^2}$. We cannot integrate this to $-\displaystyle \frac{1}{x}$ because the integrand and the integrating variable are different. Remember, the integrand must ONLY have the integrating variable and coefficients (and maybe some constants).

Comment: Oh, that...but you cannot substitute back that way! What about that $\;dt\;$ there, for example??

Comment: Exactly. So we have to either make the integral only contain functions of $x$ and $dx$ (which would bring us back to square one), or keep it with only functions of $t$ and $dt$.

Comment: Oops, yeah. My problem was that I used x and x, and so instead of "dt" I had another "dx" and I forgot that they are not interchangeable.

Comment: That's why you do NOT use the same variable when substituting!

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2 \mathrm{(9-x^2)}^{-\frac{1}{2}}}$$$$=\int \frac{dx}{x^3 \mathrm{(9/x^2-1^)}^{-\frac{1}{2}}}.$$Now take $\mathrm9{x}^{-2}-1=t$ and solve

Comment: Sorry, why does the x^2 outside of the square root become x^3?

Comment: Taking out the factor of $x^2$ from bracket

Comment: @DevgeetPatel, the minus sign in that exponent is wrong...

Comment: But other than that, his method is completely right if the power is 1/2. I prefer this over trig substitution. (+1)